# Bogus data in onPictureTaken on HTC Desire S

Tags: android, camera

I'm trying to takePicture(), following docs and examples.

Everything seems to work, except that pictures are corrupted (they are JPEGs with right dimensions, but the image is totally wrong).
Finally, I've tried Mark Murphy's 
[Camera/Picture example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Picture)
but the result was the same:[bogus image](http://www.common-lisp.ru/photo.jpg)

What could be wrong?